# SSRS expression to Convert date time to output as text

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have an expression which is returning an #Error and I believe this may be due to a data type mismatch.

I have the below expression and wanted to see if this could be converted to a text without affecting its dateadd function.

I am using this in a column group.

```
   =SWITCH(    Fields!Type_of.Value = "4) Overdue Week 1 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 1), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value,7), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "5) Overdue Week 2 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value,8), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 14), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "6) Overdue Week 3 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 15), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 21), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "7) Overdue Week 4 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 22), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 28), "dd-MM-yyyy"), 
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "8) Overdue Week 5 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 29), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 35), "dd-MM-yyyy"), 
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "9) Overdue Week 6 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 36), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 42), "dd-MM-yyyy"),  
            True, format(Fields!Type_of.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")
)
```

This is the error that is returned - The Conversion to type Double is not valid
Any tips and advice appreciated

Comment: Actually, I think it's the last `Fields!Type_of.Value` that's the problem. It's a date field while the others are strings. Convert the last one with `FORMAT(Fields!Type_of.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")` to convert it to a string.

Comment: Thanks @HannoverFist 

I made the change but it still returns with #Errror

There are no errors when compiling though

Comment: This is the error that is returned - The Conversion to type Double is not valid

Comment: Oh duh - your Dateadd should have the date **last** - `DATEADD("d", 1, Parameters!inpdate.Value)` It's trying to convert the date to an INT.

Comment: I made those changes and now it's coming back as the date format e.g. dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: There are also warnings saying, conversion from type Date to type Double is not valid

Comment: I removed the last format and it worked, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to convert the dates you are calculating with `DATEADD()` to strings so they can be concatenated with the "-".

try something like

```
Fields!Type_of.Value = "5) Overdue Week 2 - '", FORMAT(DATEADD("d", 8, Parameters!inpdate.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & FORMAT(DATEADD("d", 14, Parameters!inpdate.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
```

and repeat for all instances of DATEADD... Just edit the format string is you need a different structure to your dates.

Comment: =SWITCH(    Fields!Type_of.Value = "4) Overdue Week 1 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 1), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value,7), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "5) Overdue Week 2 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value,8), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 14), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
            Fields!Type_of.Value = "6) Overdue Week 3 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 15), "dd-MM-yyyy")

Comment: & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 21), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
   Fields!Type_of.Value = "7) Overdue Week 4 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 22), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 28), "dd-MM-yyyy"), 
   Fields!Type_of.Value = "8) Overdue Week 5 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 29), "dd-MM-yyyy") 
)

Comment: & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 35), "dd-MM-yyyy"), 
   Fields!Type_of.Value = "9) Overdue Week 6 - '", 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 36), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "-" & 
FORMAT(DATEADD("d", Parameters!inpdate.Value, 42), "dd-MM-yyyy"),  
            True, FORMAT(Fields!Type_of.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")

Comment: Thats full expression

Comment: please edit your question and add the updated expression instead of using comments

Comment: Hi @Alan just did that before your comment.

Comment: I hadn't noticed before but you have the arguments in the wrong order for `DATEADD` . The increment is the second argument not the third so it should be `DATEADD("d", 8, Parameters!inpdate.Value)` for example. I've corrected my original answer to include both fixes.